# Unable to read REF_CURSOR with StoredProcedureItemReader

Tags: java, spring, oracle, jdbc, spring-batch

I try to call stored proc

```
create or replace PROCEDURE "PROC"(cur OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
```

with this bean.

```
@Bean
    StoredProcedureItemReader<?> itemReader() {
        StoredProcedureItemReader<?> storedProcedureItemReader = new StoredProcedureItemReader<>();
        storedProcedureItemReader.setDataSource(dataSource);
        storedProcedureItemReader.setProcedureName("PROC");
        storedProcedureItemReader.setRefCursorPosition(1);
        storedProcedureItemReader.setRowMapper(new ColumnMapRowMapper());
        storedProcedureItemReader.open(new ExecutionContext());
        return storedProcedureItemReader;
    }
```

But i get

```
org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.open(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:134)
    ... 54 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column index
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatement.registerOutParameterInternal(OracleCallableStatement.java:125)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatement.registerOutParameter(OracleCallableStatement.java:304)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatement.registerOutParameter(OracleCallableStatement.java:393)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatementWrapper.registerOutParameter(OracleCallableStatementWrapper.java:1569)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.database.StoredProcedureItemReader.openCursor(StoredProcedureItemReader.java:202)
    ... 56 more
```

How can I call the PROC with just one out cursor and get iterate the result?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add a parameter to the reader for the out parameter `cur`.  Try adding the following line before you open the `storedProcedureItemReader`:

```
    storedProcedureItemReader.setParameters(new SqlParameter[] { new SqlParameter("cur", OracleTypes.CURSOR) });
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats how I use here, we must set cursor´s position otherwise spring will try to do a getObject( 0 )!

```
@Bean
    public ItemReader<FailuredProcess> getFailuredProcessReader() throws BatchOMSException {
        StoredProcedureItemReader<FailuredProcess> reader;

        try {
            reader = new StoredProcedureItemReader<FailuredProcess>();

            reader.setDataSource(dataSource);
            reader.setProcedureName(queryHelper.getQuery("query.oms.listFailuredProcessJobs"));
            reader.setRowMapper(new AlarmRowMapper());
            reader.setPreparedStatementSetter(new PreparedStatementSetterAdapter());
            reader.setVerifyCursorPosition(false);
            reader.setParameters(new SqlParameter[] { new SqlParameter("cur", OracleTypes.CURSOR) });
            reader.setRefCursorPosition(NumberUtils.INTEGER_ONE);
            reader.afterPropertiesSet();

            return reader;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error(e.getMessage(), e);
            throw new BatchOMSException(e);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

@Bean 
    @Profile("package")
    public ItemReader readerProcedureCall() throws Exception {
        StoredProcedureItemReader reader = new StoredProcedureItemReader<>();

```
    LOGGER.info("***** About getting ResultSet From Procedure **** ");
    reader.setDataSource(omniflowDataSource);
    reader.setProcedureName("proce name");
    reader.setRowMapper(new CustomRowMapper());
    reader.setPreparedStatementSetter(new PreparedStatementSetter(){
        @Override
        public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps) throws SQLException{
             CallableStatement eventCallableSt=(CallableStatement)ps;
                eventCallableSt.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.CURSOR);
        }
    });
    reader.setVerifyCursorPosition(false);
    reader.setParameters(new SqlParameter[] {new SqlParameter("pCusRecOut",OracleTypes.CURSOR)});
    reader.setRefCursorPosition(NumberUtils.INTEGER_ONE);
    reader.afterPropertiesSet();

    return reader;
}
```

Comment: Please update your answer with more details, a code only answer is not that helpful + spend some time formatting

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the code below can help you create a procedure with the output parameter as SYS_REFCURSOR:

```
StoredProcedureItemReader<?> reader = new StoredProcedureItemReader<>();
reader.setDataSource(dataSource_instance);
reader.setProcedureName("procedurename");
reader.setRowMapper(new CustomRowMapper());
reader.setPreparedStatementSetter(new PreparedStatementSetter(){
    @Override
    public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps) throws SQLException{
         CallableStatement eventCallableSt=(CallableStatement)ps;
            eventCallableSt.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.CURSOR);
    }
});
reader.setVerifyCursorPosition(false);
reader.setParameters(new SqlParameter[] {new SqlParameter(<name>,OracleTypes.CURSOR)});
reader.setRefCursorPosition(1);
reader.open(new ExecutionContext());
try {
    reader.afterPropertiesSet();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return reader;
```